# Problem normalizing log_e "Pitch" voiceAnalytics Swift iOS 13

Tags: swift, ios13, voice-recognition, speech, pitch

I am retrieving values from SFVoiceAnalytics "Pitch." My goal is to transform the data to the raw Fundamental Frequency. According to the documentation the values are returned log_e. 
When I apply exp() to the values returned I get the following ranges:

- Male voice: [0.25, 1.85], expected: [85, 180]
- Female voice: [0.2,1.6], expected: [165, 255]

For sake of simplicity I am using Apple's sample code "Recognizing Speech in Live Audio."

Thanks for the help!!

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfvoiceanalytics/3229976-pitch

```
if let result = result {                
    // returned pitch values
    for segment in result.bestTranscription.segments {
        if let pitchSegment = segment.voiceAnalytics?.pitch.acousticFeatureValuePerFrame {
            for p in pitchSegment {
                let pitch = exp(p)
                print(pitch)
            }
        }
    }
    // Update the text view with the results.
    self.textView.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
    isFinal = result.isFinal
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem lately and ultimately used another solution to retrieve pitch data.

I went with a pitch detection library for Swift called [Beethoven](https://github.com/vadymmarkov/Beethoven). It detects pitches in real-time, whereas the voice analytics of SFSpeechRecognizer only returns them once the transcription is complete.

Beethoven hasn't been updated to work with Swift 5, but I didn't find it too difficult to get it to work.

Also, upon digging up why the values in voiceAnalytics were as they were, I found out via the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfvoiceanalytics/3229976-pitch) that the pitch is a *normalized pitch estimate*:

> The value is a logarithm (base e) of the normalized pitch estimate for each frame.

My interpretation of this is likely that the values were normalized (divided by) the fundamental frequency, so I'm not sure it's possible to use this data to recover the absolute frequencies. It seems best used to convey interval changes from pitch-to-pitch.